# Using count within another select

Tags: hql

I get this exception:
`<AST>:0:0: unexpected AST node: query
 right-hand operand of a binary operator was null
<AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
 right-hand operand of a binary operator was null`

While running this HQL query

`select p.nicenumber from thosenumbers p, thesenumbers w where p.datnumber - (select count(*) from thatnumbers b where b.thisnumber = '123' and b.coolnumber = w.coolnumber) > 0`

Its a syntax issue since it runs perfectly in my database visualizer

Comment: Please include the entire HQL query.  Note that just because it is valid SQL does not mean it is valid HQL (though the reverse might be true).

Comment: i edited it, althought the hql runs fine without: "- (stuff)"

Comment: I'm not sure that HQL can handle this query.

Answer (score 0):

i was overthinking it and the answer was simply `where p.datnumber > (select count(*) from thatnumbers b where b.thisnumber = '123' and b.coolnumber = w.coolnumber)`